# Determine duration of events in Kusto?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, kql

How do I calculate durations using Kusto in the following example?

**Goal:** Determine total "handling time" of a blob in Azure Blob Storage

**Background:**

- Blob is uploaded to Storage Account using Azure Data Factory (ADF).

  - This consists of several API calls and methods (`CreatePathFile`, `LeaseFile`, `AppendFile`, `FlushFile`, `LeaseFile`) to the Storage Account.
  - An typical end-to-end ADF upload of a large file looks like:
    [image]
    [image]
- Blob is then downloaded from Storage Account using an Azure Function

  - This consists also of several API calls (but only `GetBlob` methods)
  - Looks largely the same
    [image]

So now I've combined both of these queries to show all `OperationNames` performed on a given blob:

- Query:

```
//==================================================//
// Assign variables
//==================================================//
let varStart = ago(2d);
let varEnd = now();
let varStorageAccount = 'stgaccountname';
let varSampleUploadUri = 'https://stgaccountname.dfs.core.windows.net/containername/filename.csv';
let varSampleDownloadUri = replace(@'%2F', @'/', replace(@'.dfs.', @'.blob.', tostring(varSampleUploadUri)));
//==================================================//
// Filter table
//==================================================//
StorageBlobLogs
| where TimeGenerated between (varStart .. varEnd)
  and AccountName == varStorageAccount
  //and StatusText == varStatus
  and split(Uri, '?')[0] == varSampleUploadUri
  or split(Uri, '?')[0] == varSampleDownloadUri
//==================================================//
// Group and parse results
//==================================================//
| summarize 
  count() by OperationName,
  TimeGenerated,
  UserAgent = tostring(split(UserAgentHeader, ' ')[0]),
  ChunkSize = iif(OperationName == 'GetBlob', format_bytes(ResponseBodySize, 2, 'MB'), format_bytes(RequestBodySize, 2, 'MB')),
  StatusCode,
  StatusText
| order by TimeGenerated asc
```

- Results: A nice combined table
  [image]

**Question is:**

- How do I adjust the query to show the duration from the earliest `TimeGenerated` event to the last `TimeGenerated` event?

  - This would show the duration between first upload API call and final download API call.

Comment: The question is very long and contains a lot of info that seems irrelevant. If I understand the question correctly, the only relevant piece of information here is the final result table that you have. Please edit the question and only supply a sample dataset (in datatable format), and expected output.

Comment: Mocking up data is not something I've yet done in Azure Log Analytics. I'll keep this in mind for future posts.

Comment: Following your advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67926763/start-and-end-times-by-operationname-in-kusto)

Comment: Great, thanks, looks much better :)  (and I've just answered that question :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
YourQuery
| summarize Duration = max(TimeGenerated) - min(TimeGenerated)
```

Here's an example with some synthetic data in datatable format:

```
datatable(Timestamp:datetime, SomeGuid:string)
[
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:03:59.5708689Z), "2e76bf18-04ed-4d3f-afe3-cff87c532b10", 
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:04:03.3834404Z), "27a7f8ec-f0a7-4fad-9784-996051d2a9f9", 
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:06.1334979Z), "568ab8a4-2ed2-486f-a7b9-1d27379b52db", 
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:06:20.3212560Z), "edd1f7d2-5fc5-482f-88d3-6ad16a1ae000", 
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:07:30.6034174Z), "cf5cb66b-05b1-43f3-ad04-23c56f96687e", 
]
| summarize Duration = max(Timestamp) - min(Timestamp)
```

Output:

```
00:03:31.0325485
```

Comment: This did work well. Thank you. Do you have ideas for how to do it for each group of records in a table rather than just a single record? Something like, *for each `Uri`* summarize Duration = max(Timestamp) - min(Timestamp). When I try to add any other value under summarize, I get an aggregation error (not allowed).

Comment: Sure. Try this: `| summarize Duration = max(Timestamp) - min(Timestamp) by Uri`

Comment: Aha! The `by` keyword did the trick. Much thanks.