# Start and End Times by OperationName in Kusto?

Tags: azure-log-analytics, kql

How to add a `StartTime` and `EndTime` for each `OperationName` in the example below?

**Sample data:**

```
datatable(TimeGenerated:datetime, OperationName:string, ChunkSize:string, StatusCode:string, Filename:string, UserAgent:string)
[
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:03:59.5708689Z), "CreateFilePath", "0MB", "201", "test_file.csv", "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:04:03.3834404Z), "LeaseFile",  "0MB", "201", "test_file.csv",  "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:06.1334979Z), "AppendFile", "8MB", "206", "test_file.csv", "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:07.1334979Z), "AppendFile", "8MB", "206", "test_file.csv", "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:08.1334979Z), "AppendFile", "8MB", "206", "test_file.csv", "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:09.1334979Z), "AppendFile", "8MB", "206", "test_file.csv", "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:10.1334979Z), "AppendFile", "8MB", "206", "test_file.csv", "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:11.1334979Z), "AppendFile", "8MB", "206", "test_file.csv", "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:12.1334979Z), "AppendFile", "8MB", "206", "test_file.csv", "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:13.1334979Z), "FlushFile", "0MB", "200", "test_file.csv", "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:14.1334979Z), "LeaseFile", "0MB", "200", "test_file.csv", "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:15.1334979Z), "GetBlob", "256MB", "206", "test_file.csv", "azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.8.1 Python/3.8.10",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:16.1334979Z), "GetBlob", "128MB", "206", "test_file.csv", "azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.8.1 Python/3.8.10",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:17.1334979Z), "GetBlob", "128MB", "206", "test_file.csv", "azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.8.1 Python/3.8.10",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:18.1334979Z), "GetBlob", "128MB", "206", "test_file.csv", "azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.8.1 Python/3.8.10",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:19.1334979Z), "GetBlob", "128MB", "206", "test_file.csv", "azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.8.1 Python/3.8.10",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:20.1334979Z), "GetBlob", "128MB", "206", "test_file.csv", "azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.8.1 Python/3.8.10"
]
| summarize MethodCount = count() by OperationName, Filename, UserAgent
```

**Results:**

```
OperationName   FileName        UserAgent                                       MethodCount
CreateFilePath  test_file.csv   Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer                1   
LeaseFile       test_file.csv   Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer                2   
AppendFile      test_file.csv   Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer                7   
FlushFile       test_file.csv   Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer                1   
GetBlob         test_file.csv   azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.8.1 Python/3.8.10  6
```

**Need:**

```
StartTime                       EndTime                         OperationName   FileName        UserAgent                                       MethodCount
2021-05-27T06:03:59.5708689Z    2021-05-27T06:03:59.5708689Z    CreateFilePath  test_file.csv   Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer                1   
2021-05-27T06:04:03.3834404Z    2021-05-27T06:05:14.1334979Z    LeaseFile       test_file.csv   Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer                2   
2021-05-27T06:05:06.1334979Z    2021-05-27T06:05:12.1334979Z    AppendFile      test_file.csv   Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer                7   
2021-05-27T06:05:13.1334979Z    2021-05-27T06:05:13.1334979Z    FlushFile       test_file.csv   Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer                1   
2021-05-27T06:05:15.1334979Z    2021-05-27T06:05:20.1334979Z    GetBlob         test_file.csv   azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.8.1 Python/3.8.10  6
```

**Tried:**

```
| summarize
  StartTime = min(TimeGenerated) by OperationName, 
  EndTime = max(TimeGenerated) by OperationName`,
  MethodCount = count() by OperationName,
  Filename, 
  UserAgent
```

Comment: Hi @ericOnline. If the answer below helps, please accept it (see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top) to know why and how). If the answer below is missing some info, please add a comment describing what's missing and we'll help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Filename value for all records for a specific OperationName is going to be the same, it's sufficient to take a value from any records with this OperationName using `summarize any(Filename)`. Same with the UserAgent column.

```
datatable(TimeGenerated:datetime, OperationName:string, ChunkSize:string, StatusCode:string, Filename:string, UserAgent:string)
[
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:03:59.5708689Z), "CreateFilePath", "0MB", "201", "test_file.csv", "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:04:03.3834404Z), "LeaseFile",  "0MB", "201", "test_file.csv",  "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:06.1334979Z), "AppendFile", "8MB", "206", "test_file.csv", "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:07.1334979Z), "AppendFile", "8MB", "206", "test_file.csv", "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:08.1334979Z), "AppendFile", "8MB", "206", "test_file.csv", "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:09.1334979Z), "AppendFile", "8MB", "206", "test_file.csv", "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:10.1334979Z), "AppendFile", "8MB", "206", "test_file.csv", "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:11.1334979Z), "AppendFile", "8MB", "206", "test_file.csv", "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:12.1334979Z), "AppendFile", "8MB", "206", "test_file.csv", "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:13.1334979Z), "FlushFile", "0MB", "200", "test_file.csv", "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:14.1334979Z), "LeaseFile", "0MB", "200", "test_file.csv", "Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:15.1334979Z), "GetBlob", "256MB", "206", "test_file.csv", "azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.8.1 Python/3.8.10",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:16.1334979Z), "GetBlob", "128MB", "206", "test_file.csv", "azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.8.1 Python/3.8.10",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:17.1334979Z), "GetBlob", "128MB", "206", "test_file.csv", "azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.8.1 Python/3.8.10",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:18.1334979Z), "GetBlob", "128MB", "206", "test_file.csv", "azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.8.1 Python/3.8.10",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:19.1334979Z), "GetBlob", "128MB", "206", "test_file.csv", "azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.8.1 Python/3.8.10",
    datetime(2021-05-27T06:05:20.1334979Z), "GetBlob", "128MB", "206", "test_file.csv", "azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.8.1 Python/3.8.10"
]
| summarize StartTime=min(TimeGenerated), EndTime=max(TimeGenerated), Filename=any(Filename), UserAgent=any(UserAgent), MethodCount=count() by OperationName
| project-reorder StartTime, EndTime, OperationName, Filename, UserAgent, MethodCount
```

Output:

| StartTime | EndTime | OperationName | Filename | UserAgent | MethodCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-27 06:03:59.5708689 | 2021-05-27 06:03:59.5708689 | CreateFilePath | test_file.csv | Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer | 1 |
| 2021-05-27 06:04:03.3834404 | 2021-05-27 06:05:14.1334979 | LeaseFile | test_file.csv | Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer | 2 |
| 2021-05-27 06:05:06.1334979 | 2021-05-27 06:05:12.1334979 | AppendFile | test_file.csv | Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer | 7 |
| 2021-05-27 06:05:13.1334979 | 2021-05-27 06:05:13.1334979 | FlushFile | test_file.csv | Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer | 1 |
| 2021-05-27 06:05:15.1334979 | 2021-05-27 06:05:20.1334979 | GetBlob | test_file.csv | azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.8.1 Python/3.8.10 | 6 |